# Where can I list my DNA in Europe (England) to improve the chances of making a match with other researchers?

Tags: england, dna

My DNA is listed on several USA sites.  Does any one know of similar sites in Europe (England) where I  can try to make a match?

Comment: Welcome to Genealogy.stackexchange. I've edited the title to make it into a question -- pleease correct the edits if I've misrepresented what you're asking. Also, it could help if you gave examples of the specific USA sites where your DNA is listed.

Answer (score 3):

The article [*DNA testing for Genealogy* by 
Iain Kennedy](http://www.genuki.org.uk/big/bigmisc/DNA.html) posted on GENUKI 
discusses a number of UK genetic genealogy projects centred around surnames 
(for example, Clan Macgregor) or geographical locations (such as Shetland Islands).

Depending on your history, one of those might match your needs.

Answer (score 3):

I have a list of DNA projects for the British Isles on my blog:

http://cruwys.blogspot.co.uk/2009/08/dna-projects-for-british-isles.html

Virtually all the British-led DNA projects are hosted at Family Tree DNA in America.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, there are no UK-located DNA-testing services for genealogists at present (October 2012). Those UK genealogists that I know have done DNA testing have used the various services in the USA.